# How to sending build to client in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I read so many documents on how to send build to APP but still I have doubt in that. Can any one please tell me the step by step procedure. And is it necessary to have a Paid Apple ID to send build. Do I need to add client (user/tester) in the users. What are the certificates I should have. and about the Key Chaining if it is included in the process of sending build. Please let me know its so important for me to know. Because I have to send a Build to my client.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: I think you are asking too much here... All of these are broad topics and needs at least some prior knowledge. Community can then help you by addressing specific query/issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a broad topic,and a simple [google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=itunes%20connect%20submit%20build) would have helped you.

Go to the itunesconnect guides and they have beautiful docs with step by step procedure and screenshots.

[Upload a build](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html)

[Distrubute a build](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html)

And,

1. Do you need a Paid Apple developer account - **YES**
2. Do you need to add client as a testers in your itunes team - **YES**
3. What are the certificate you should use - **Distribution certificate**, build should be signed by a Ad-Hoc prov. file

Comment: sorry for the long question but I was confused with all the documents. So I want to confirm which one is correct. And thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Testflight: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ or http://www.diawi.com/

For more info and step by step please search some tutorials, it's too long to explain here, some tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial
http://techapple.net/2015/01/4-waysmethods-install-ipa-file-app-iphone-ipad-ipod-online-offline-methods/

Comment: sorry for the long question but I was confused with all the documents. So I want to confirm which one is correct. And thank you for the answers.